# Printing integer from function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to return an integer from a function and print it outside of the function and I can't get it to work.

I've tried googling it but I can't find a good answer.

```
def lukusarjanSumma(lukun):
    tulos = (1 + lukun) * (lukun - 1 + 1) / 2
    return tulos

print('Lukusarjan summa n=100:', tulos)
print(tulos)
```

I expect the output to print `5050.00`.

Comment: I guess the second print should be print(lukusarjanSumma(tulos))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call your function. This works (but gives a float):

```
def lukusarjanSumma(lukun): 
   tulos = (1 + lukun) * (lukun - 1 + 1) / 2  
   return tulos 


tulos = lukusarjanSumma(100) 
print('Lukusarjan summa n=100:', tulos)                                 

# prints Lukusarjan summa n=100: 5050.00
```

this would give you an integer

```
def lukusarjanSumma_int(lukun): 
    tulos = (1 + lukun) * (lukun - 1 + 1) // 2  
    return tulos 


tulos = lukusarjanSumma_int(100) 
print('Lukusarjan summa n=100:', tulos)   

# prints Lukusarjan summa n=100: 5050
```

Comment: @uneven_mark Maybe you are right – this was copy and paste from the  ipython interactive shell. However it hinders copying and pasting by other people, so that they really have to read and understand the code. But yes – your answer is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling your function correctly. If this is your function:

```
def lukusarjanSumma(lukun): 
    tulos = (1 + lukun) * (lukun - 1 + 1) / 2 
    return tulos
```

You can call it like this:

```
tulos = lukusarjanSumma(n) # n or an integer like 100
```

You can then print the result, there's many ways to do that:

```
# if you want to assign the result to a variable first
print("Lukusarjan summa n=100: {}".format(tulos))
print(f"Lukusarjan summa n=100: {tulos}")

# if you want to print it directly
print("Lukusarjan summa n=100: {}".format(lukusarjanSumma(n)))
print(f"Lukusarjan summa n=100: {lukusarjanSumma(n)}")
print("Lukusarjan summa n=100: " + lukusarjanSumma(n))

# they will all output this:
# Lukusarjan summa n=100: 5050.0
```

If you just want to print the result of the function, you could just do it like so:

```
print(lukujarsanSumma(n))
```